# Unable to query Account Fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, account

I have created a VF page in two of my salesforce Org. The VF page is used as a SOQL Query Tool. On running the query on the VF page I am receiving the error:

> No such column '#field name ' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The field that are giving me error are `Jigsaw`, `JigsawCompanyId`, `AccountSource`, `SicDesc` on the `Account` object

However things are working fine on the other sandbox account with the same VF page.

Is there any extra permission that need to be given.The query works fine on workbench

Answer (score 1):

This issue is almost certainly caused by `Field Level Security`. Click into each field and click the <kbd>Set Field Level Security</kbd> button. Then make sure `Visible` is checked.

Also make sure you [Set Up Data.com Users](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=jigsaw_int_enabling_users.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: It works fine on another network , However it gives me the error on my side is there any network or security issue that may cause this

Comment: @cloudlover Your FLS settings can vary from org to org...did you check that it is indeed visible in the org that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Yep Its visible and its default system admin profile. One thing more the functionality is working fine on salesforce support end.

Comment: @cloudlover Added another link you may find helpful. Please make sure you have followed those steps.